# how to retrieve All custom labels and validation rules in eclips IDE using package.xml In salesforce

Tags: apex, deployment, package.xml

Need all custom labels and Validation rules in Eclipse to check references.

how to retrieve All custom labels and validation rules in eclips IDE using package.xml In sales force

Comment: Thanks.Got it.     How can i get all visualforce pages in eclips by using package.xml

Comment: All vf pages needs to be retrieve using package.xml in eclips

Answer (score 2):

To get Custom Labels and Validation Rules you have to add `CustomLabels` and `CustomObject` as below in the package XML. The validation rules are part of objects and when you add `CustomObject` you will get all the validation rules part of object configuration itself. Hope this helps.

Package XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    ....
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    ......
</Package>
```

Object configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    ................    
    <validationRules>
    ..........
    </validationRules>
    ................
</CustomObject>
```

Answer (score 1):

All validation rules are included in object XML.
Labels have separated folder.

Try:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomLabels</name>
</types>


<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```